# Questions on SQL* Loader commit range and display

Tags: oracle, unix, oracle9i, sql-loader

As per my observation, when we load the data to Oracle tables using SQL* Loader, 64 records are committed at once, by default.

Could you please let me know if we can change this default limit of insertion/commit to number other than 64?

Also, can we avoid the display of loading, shown below on the console?

```
Commit point reached - logical record count 64
Commit point reached - logical record count 128
Commit point reached - logical record count 192
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_params.htm):

> `rows` -- number of rows in conventional path bind array or between direct
>   path data saves
>    (Default: Conventional path 64, Direct path all)

So you'd specify `rows=1024` or whatever on the command line or parameter file.

As for avoiding the display, I don't think there's an option to suppress only the progress information. There is `silent` but that might be more than you want. Filter those out with `grep` if you don't want to see them.

Comment: Thank U Mat...:) I shall implement these and update on the output on Monday....Thanks again..:)

Comment: Hi Mat...your reply helped me increase the commit point to maximum 1706 rows. I mean whetever range I give in "rows", say 2000, 5000, etc., it is always committing at 1706 rows. I couldn't understand this. Is this the maximum commit point it can reach?

Comment: There's also the `bindsize` parameter that could influence this. Please read the docs about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mat...I am able to commit at a higher range now. :)